# Check if Cursor is hovering over the top X amount of pixel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use Javascript/jQuery to check to see if your cursor is hovering over the top 20 pixels *or so* of the webpage?

Example:

> Similar to how the exit bar works on windows 8. You have to hover at
>   the top of the screen for a second or so for the *close minimize*
>   options to appear.

I wondered if this is possible to replicate *purely* with Javascript/jQuery, to then allow a `jQuery.fadeIn()` or `jQuery.slideDown()` to take place.

Hopefully it's possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, with a mouse event and checking if `e.pageY` is less than 20px, you're mouse is in the top 20 pixels etc.

```
var isOnTop = false;

$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    isOnTop = e.pageY < 20;
});
```

I'll add a few examples, keeping the mouse still at the top for a second will trigger the event

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));

    if ( e.pageY < 20 ) {
        $(this).data('timer',
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#top').slideDown()
            }, 1000)
        );
    }
});

$('#top').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6pcap61w/)

Any movement at the top requires a little more code, and another variable to keep from removing the timer

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {

    if ( e.pageY < 20 ) {
        if ( ! $(this).data('isSet') ) {
            $(this).data('timer',
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#top').slideDown()
                    $(this).data('isSet', false);
                }, 1000)
            ).data('isSet', true);
        }
    } else {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
        $(this).data('isSet', false);
    }
});

$('#top').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6pcap61w/1/)

Comment: would you be able to throw together a quick http://jsfiddle.net so it's easier for a noob like me to understand how this would work, if I wanted an element to appear after reaching the top 20pixels? pls.

Comment: Whenever the mouse is in the top part of the page for more than a second, or just if you keep the mouse pointer still for a second, not quite sure how windows 8 works

Comment: it has a one or two second wait until it fades in the topbar, thats why i was wondering about a demo :P

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `mousemove` listener to `body`. Also, you should create a boolean flag (variable or [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). In that listener you check if the mouse is in the top *x* px of the page, and set the flag to that boolean value.

If the flag changed by that operation, either

- `setTimeout` for showing something, if the flag changed to `true`.
- `clearTimeout` said timeout and hide the thing of shown, if the flag changed to `false`.

I believe you'll be able to implement this based on my answer. I'll be happy to give more instructions, but I'm not going to give you copypastible JS code.

**Pseudocode:**

```
flag = false

when mouse moved over page {
    if mouse y < value and flag = false {
        flag = true
        show after 1 second
    } 
    if mouse y > value and flag = true {
        flag = false 
        cancel showing
        hide if shown 
    } 
}
```